# Simple form not submitting to database PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

Banging my head on the wall trying to figure out why my information isn't being submitted into my MySQL database. All connection info is correct, I use 1 connection script and everything else is still working fine. PHP for submit is very basic while I'm testing, (i.e. sanitation and validation  will come after I am submitting properly). But for whatever reason, this code will not submit. its the same code I'm using elsewhere so its only this one that is having issues.

PHP Code

```
<?php       

if(isset($_POST["schcreate"])){

error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $name = "";

  $location = "";

  $daystart = "";

  $shiftcount = "";

  $startdate = "";

 include_once("../php_includes/db_connect.php");

 $name = $_POST['schname'];

 $location = $_POST['schlocation'];

 $daystart = $_POST['schday'];

 $shiftcount = $_POST['schshiftcount'];

 $startdate = $_POST['schstart'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO schinformations (schname, schlocation, schdaystart, schshiftcount, schstartdate) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$daystart', '$shiftcount', '$startdate');";

$query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql); 

}
?>
```

HTML Code

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="schq">Schedule Name:</div>
<div class="scha"><input type="text" id="schname" name="schname" /></div>
<div class="schq">Location:</div>
<div class="scha"><input type="text" id="schlocation" name="schlocation" /></div>
<div class="schq">Day of the week the schedule starts on:</div>
<div class="scha"><select id="schday" name="schday">
                <option value="default">Select </option>
                <option>Monday</option>
                <option>Tuesday</option>
                <option>Wednesday</option>
                <option>Thursday</option>
                <option>Friday</option>
                <option>Saturday</option>
                <option>Sunday</option>
            </select>
</div>
<div class="schq">Number of Shifts:</div>
<div class="scha"><input type="text" id="schshiftcount" name="schshiftcount" /></div>
<div class="schq">Start Date:</div>
<div class="scha"><input type="text" id="schstart" name="schstart" /></div>
<div class="schq">Next Step:</div>
<div class="scha"><input type="submit" id="schcreate" value="Create Shifts"/></div>
</form>
```

I have tried everything I can think of to see what's going on but I'm not getting any errors. Can anyone see what I am not here?

Thanks

Comment: echo the content of `$sql` before you run the query

Comment: you're missing the `name` attribute for your submit button `schcreate` so you don't get a value in $_POST for that key and your condition is not met so the query doesn't run

Comment: @koala_dev you're right - but it's not part of the query.

Comment: @alfasin it's in the condition that is needed to run the query `if(isset($_POST["schcreate"]))`

Comment: @alfasin pretty important if the script doesn't detect the submission of the form though!

Comment: @koala_dev I suspect that this parameter is redundant - he could use any other parameter - but chose to add another one for the task - so when the page is loaded without the form being submitted - this logic won't run.

Comment: Yes they are both in the same file.

Comment: @koala_dev I added the `name` addtribute but that didn't change anything, still not submitting.

Comment: @PHaeLiX see my first comment! print `$sql` and then, if the query is valid - try to run it directly in the DB and see why it's rejected - maybe you have some unique constraints or something

Comment: @koala_dev post that as the answer and I'll mark it correct. I found one other issue but this was the main one. Seems odd that some of my other forms are submitting without the `name` attribute. any idea why that would be allowed one time but not another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `name` attribute for your submit button so there's no `schcreate` key in `$_POST` and your query doesn't run.

You can eliminate the need for the `name` attribute by checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to get the request type, also you should use `isset` in each of your post values, so you could rewrite your code like this:

```
<?php       
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        include_once("../php_includes/db_connect.php");
        $name = isset($_POST['schname']) ? $_POST['schname'] : '';
        $location = isset($_POST['schlocation']) ? $_POST['schlocation'] : '';
        $daystart = isset($_POST['schday']) ? $_POST['schday'] : '';
        $shiftcount = isset($_POST['schshiftcount']) ? $_POST['schshiftcount'] : '';
        $startdate = isset($_POST['schstart']) ? $_POST['schstart'] : '';

        $sql = "INSERT INTO schinformations (schname, schlocation, schdaystart, schshiftcount, schstartdate) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$daystart', '$shiftcount', '$startdate');";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: If I apply `isset` to all of them, this would also work to make sure there is something in them too correct? Thanks again for the help

Comment: @PHaeLiX isset will check if there's a value in that index, in my example I set a value of an empty string if the index is not found in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple:

```
<div class="scha"><input type="submit" id="schcreate" value="Create Shifts"/></div>
```

is supposed to be:

```
<div class="scha"><input type="submit" id="schcreate" name="schcreate" value="Create Shifts"/></div>
```